# Pacman hook 'failed to run transaction hooks' error

Tags: manjaro, pacman

I was attempting a full Manjaro update using `sudo pacman -Syyu`, but at the end, it threw the error:

```
Error: hook /usr/share/libalpm/hooks/gtk-query-immodules-3.0.hook line 2: invalid value Path
Error: failed to commit transaction (failed to run transaction hooks)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

How can I fix the hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you don't maintain your system regularly. The quickest fix is to update Pacman by -

```
wget https://pkgbuild.com/~eschwartz/repo/x86_64-extracted/pacman-static
chmod +x pacman-static
sudo ./pacman-static -Syyu
```

I don't think it is the cleanest way but it should update Pacman without any problem.

Another way to tackle this problem -

`sudo nano /usr/share/libalpm/hooks/gtk-query-immodules-3.0.hook`

Change Type = **Path** to Type = **File** in line 2

Reinstall the kernel, I'm assuming the version

`sudo pacman -S kernel419`

Run these -

`sudo mkinitcpio -P`

`sudo update-grub`

I'd try to update Pacman first and see if the issue gets solved.

Comment: Thank you, rubaiat, that worked perfectly.